# Upgrade and use latest Python on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python3

I'm trying to install, and use, `Python3.10` as default on my `Ubuntu 20.04` machine. So I followed [this](https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/upgrade-python-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-linux) guide on the matter. The guide worked, almost, as intended until I ran a `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y`, where it prompted me to remove unused packages. Which I then did subsequently breaking my system.

Amongst other things - which I ignored initially - it removed `genome`-related stuff, and `xserver-xorg`-related packages.

How do I set it up properly, and avoid the essential packages becoming unused? Is this even a possibility? Im aware that the guide says that `Python 3.10` is not supported by `Ubuntu 20.04` but if the guide made it work on a VM, I assume it is possible on a live version?

Comment: Changing default python breaks Ubuntu. So don't do it.

Comment: Is that just 'how it is', or is there a work around if you spend enough time on it?

Comment: A lot of programs depend on the default python version. You can use all kinds of python on your system, but not as a default one. This is "how it is".

Comment: First of all, what are you trying to achieve? System programs are supposed to use Python which came with the system. I guess you want to use different Python version for your specific app. In that case use Python virtual environment, it is the way to go, it is distro independent and that way you can use as many different Python versions as you want without breaking things.